# Internationalization of measuring units in Android

Tags: android, internationalization, units-of-measurement

In my application, there are inputs like length, weight etc. Different countries follow different measurement guidelines, like in US its miles, gallons and UK is km, litres. So does android Locale support such conversions on locale changes or do we have to code it explicitly.

Comment: actually, in the UK it's miles (for anything road/long-distance based, miles per hour for speed, etc.) but generally metric for everything else (weight - kg, volume - L, temperature - Celsius, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do something like this :

```
 if (locale.getCountry().equals("US")){
 // Code to compute weight based on USA format
 }

 else {
 // Code to compute weight based on metric system
 }
```

Other than US , Burma and Liberia have non-metric format

Answer (score 0):

My wouldn't that be a useful feature!  No I'm afraid all you can count on `Locale` for will be to assist you in formatting decimal numbers with the appropriate grouping characters.  You will have to write the code to do the numeric conversions of your data and perhaps use the default `Locale` on the device to determine which units to display to the user.

Comment: Yeah i think we have to mention the metric-conversions explicitly in the code but as far as decimal numbers is considered I found out that we can use the object of DecimalFormat. It manages the commas and periods in the number system based on the locale.for eg: 999999.09 would be displayed as 999,999.00 in US and 999.999,00 in european countires(germany, italy etc).